# Why is my YAML value not defined when I read it in javascript but it is everywhere else?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yaml

I am trying to read a YAML file from my local dir. I can read it but the data in the file is not defined.

The error looks like this:

[image]

The data in the file is structured like this :

```
userName: myusername

options :
   displayTime : true
   displayGreating : true

fruit: 
 -apple
 -orange
```

My code said that 'myusername' is not defined. what does that mean?

I'm loading the YAML like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{this.dataNotWorkingNow}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import yaml from "js-yaml";
import fs from "fs";
import config from "./config.yml";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dataNotWorkingNow: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    fs.readFile(config, "utf8", function(e, data) {
      var file;
      if (e) {
        console.log("config.yml not found.");
      } else {
        file = yaml.safeLoad(data, "utf8");
        if (file.options["displayGreating"]) {
          console.log("hello " + file.userName);
        }
        if (file.options["displayTime"]) {
          console.log("the time is: " + new Date());
        }
      }
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

How do I load the data from the local file?

Comment: what if you put `myusername` in doublequotes?

Comment: @Honza then i just get another error that said "Error in created hook: "TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.readFile is not a function""

Comment: then it would be helpful if you posted how you resolve *.yml files in your webpack config. And search there. Yml you imported looks like resolved as a js file. Probably need to use some yml loader to use with webpack in order to be able to import yml files direclty using `import ... from` statement

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you do

```
import config from "./config.yml";
```

That statement tries to parse your YAML file as JavaScript source. Drop the line and do `fs.readFile("./config.yml", …` instead.